# Simple Flash Data type questions

Tags: flash, actionscript, types

I am trying to declare a variable for a button component in AS3.
I have one button named btn1 and tried to write:

```
import flash.controls.Button;

var btn:Button = mc.test.btn1;
```

I got an error: Definition flash.controls.Button can't not be found....

Anyone has an idea??? Thanks for the help..

Comment: If you download FlashDevelop (free), you can get some good autocompletion, e.g. typing "import Button" and pressing enter will add "import fl.controls.Button" to your imports.

Answer (score 2):

you may want to try:
import fl.controls.Button